# hardware accelerated window manager

Tags: hardware, window-manager, openbox, crunchbang

i got a hand me down lenovo thinkpad and i was pleased that it was still comparatively fast as it was running windows 7 very smoothly...

but since i switched to CrunchBang (i'd like to think i'm always squeezing everything from any gadget i have), i've seen less smooth UI rendering. as for the video playback, it isn't as smooth as before and for it, the CPU usage can take up to 60%.

now, i should've looked at the CPU usage when it was running windows 7 for video playback and UI rendering for comparison, but i didn't (i won't reinstall windows 7 just for that). so i can't say for sure that it's using more CPU time. but i think i really think there's a noticeable difference.

CrunchBang uses OpenBox, which doesn't seem to use hardware acceleration from the GPU... but is there any way that i can simply add a package so that the window manager would use hardware acceleration? say, like, the Direct Rendering Infrastructure (DRI)?

as for the video playback, perhaps i can use the Gnash flashplayer and VLC, i just hope that VA API (which on Linux, sits on top of DRI) supports my GPU.

but my main concern for now is finding an accelerated window manager.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a stand alone compositor such as xcompmgr, compton, cairo-compmgr, or unagi.

Comment: Welcomme to U&L Stackexchnage, can you give more details ?

Comment: @RaptorRed: aahhhh... i thought what you suggested might help, but it seems that xcompmgr and Compton already comes with CrunchBang...